fs_usage, output display regarding io call - the options and flags shown
I am summarising output from fs_usage with a simple awk to total io calls, io time including wait (I believe):
sudo fs_usage -f diskio | awk 'START{print "Times include async wait time"}{if(lasT>=$1){t=substr($0,110,8);ioc++;ioT+=t;appio[$NF" "$2]++;apIOT[$NF" "$2]+=t} else {if(ioc>last_ioc){print "\n"ioc" IOs\t∑s",ioT"\t"$1; for (x in appio){print appio[x]"  \t"apIOT[x]"  \t",x} ;n=0; ioc=0; ioT=0; split("",appio); split("",apIOT);last_ioc=ioc }}; lasT=$1}' &

This gives a useful summary any second that there is physical IO but I have to guess what the [content] after call type is, here is a sample...
244 IOs ∑s 0.195188 12:26:18
1   0.001309     cfprefsd WrData[AT1] 
1   0.000293     corespotlighRdData[SNT3] 
5   0.117798     corespotligh THROTTLED
173 0.063006     kernel_task WrMeta[AP]
20  0.005587     coreduetd RdData[AT1]
1   0.000214     corespotligh WrData[ANT3]
1   0.00015      cfprefsd WrData[AP]
40  0.006412     coreduetd WrData[AT1]
2   0.000419     corespotligh WrData[AT3]

Here are a few guesses,
First A=async, S=Sync
T = time-out set? 123 maybe secs for timeout
P=privileged, physical?
N=??
Can anyone confirm/correct these and maybe list others that might seen?
I found a reference to the source code for fs_usage but it was a 404...
I always assume sorting the keyed array output is too much trouble or impossible, am I missing a trick?
I also do not get my START header information visible, why?
For others that might find this info useful: where and how is THROTTLING implemented? Obviously io calls are completed more slowly... It seems odd not to discriminate Write [WTHROTTL] from Read [RTHROTTL].

I don't know why searches did not find this for me, in the various places and ways I looked.
However
What does that mean of PgIn[ST3P], RdMeta[ST3UP] when use fs_usage in osx
gives some useful data and even the source code.
A or S = async / sync
N = nocache
T is optionally followed by a number: this is something to do with P_DISKIO_TIER_MASK and P_DISKIO_TIER_SHIFT...
and then this is optionally followed by U, indicating P_DISKIO_TIER_UPGRADE
P = passive (a process may mark its I/O as passive; passive I/O may be throttled but doesn't cause throttling of other I/Os.)
PS my other questions still open.
For speedier output to a log file use
mawk -W interactive

Throttling and passive file io may get some illumination from
https://mjacobson.net/blog/2022-02-throttling.html
Some of this may explain why my 2013 iMac ran like treacle after update to Catalina. It flies now I move to boot from external USB Samsung T7 ... and thanks/kudos to Bombich for CCC making a bootable Catalina copy so well. (This may be the last macOS that could be cloned like that.)
In case that evaporates here are a few main points...
On Darwin, threads block inside throttle_lowpri_io when they're being artificially delayed to slow down their I/O operations, with the ultimate goal of optimizing the performance of higher-priority I/O. And indeed, in both of these cases (and in the other similar problems I saw), the chain of blockage ultimately leads to a thread with less-than-highest I/O priority.
..
To keep track of which I/Os should be throttled, the Darwin kernel maintains what I'll call throttling domains (the source calls them struct _throttle_io_info_t). In rough terms, each throttling domain is meant to correspond one-to-one to a disk device.
When an I/O is issued through the spec_strategy routine, the kernel has to determine which throttling domain the operation lives in, so that the operation may either be throttled or cause throttling of lower-priority operations. The throttling domain is determined first by taking the vnode (i.e., file) the I/O is being done to and walking up to its enclosing mount_t.
From there, the code looks at the mount's mnt_devbsdunit property. The mnt_devbsdunit describes the "disk number" of the device the filesystem lives on. If a filesystem is mounted from /dev/disk3, then the mount's mnt_devbsdunit is 3. If the backing disk is actually a partition of a disk, then the number comes from the whole disk, not the partition; e.g., /dev/disk3s2 results in 3.[2]
The mnt_devbsdunit—which can range from 0 to 63[3]—determines which throttling domain is in play.
..
Logical volume groups and mnt_throttle_mask
Apple added a logical volume manager, called CoreStorage, to Mac OS X Lion. In contrast to traditional disk partitions, in which a contiguous range of a disk device is used as a volume, CoreStorage allows a looser relationship between volumes and backing storage. For instance, a volume might use storage from multiple different disk devices—witness Fusion Drive for example.
This complicates the mnt_devbsdunit situation. Suppose a filesystem is mounted from volume disk2. According to the previous rules, mnt_devbsdunit is 2. However, disk2 might be a CoreStorage logical volume, backed by the real disk devices disk0 and disk1.
Moreover, CoreStorage might not be the only user of disk0 and disk1. Suppose further a second, non-CoreStorage volume on disk0, called disk0s3. I/Os to disk2 and disk0s3 may contend with each other. But the mnt_devbsdunit of disk0s3 is 0, so the two mounts will be in different throttling domains.
To solve this, enter a second mount_t field, mnt_throttle_mask. mnt_throttle_mask is a 64-bit bit array. A bit is set only when I/Os to the mount may involve the correspondingly numbered disk device. For our CoreStorage logical volume disk2, since disk0 and disk1 are included, bits 0 and 1 are set. Bit 2 is also set for the logical volume itself, so the overall mask is 0x7.
In theory, you might imagine a system wherein a mount could reside in multiple throttling domains. Or perhaps the throttling domain decision could be pushed down so that CoreStorage could help make smart decisions about which to use for a particular I/O operation.
The implemented reality is much more mundane. mnt_devbsdunit is set to the index of the lowest bit set in mnt_throttle_mask. For disk2, since bit 0 is set, mnt_devbsdunit is 0. So disk2 and disk0s3 live in the same throttling domain (though, notably, a theoretical disk1s3 would not).
This explains what's happening with /System/Volumes/Data above. disk1s1 is a logical volume presented by a volume manager[4], and its backing storage is on disk0. Tweaking the dtrace script shows that mnt_throttle_mask is 0x3:
..
Use IOPOL_PASSIVE
In addition to assigning a priority tier to its I/O operations, a process may mark its I/O as passive; passive I/O may be throttled but doesn't cause throttling of other I/Os.
Recompiling dd to call setiopolicy_np(3) would be a hassle. An easier way is to use the taskpolicy(8) modifier utility that comes with recent versions of macOS. Though not documented in the manpage, the -d option can take the argument passive, like:
# taskpolicy -d passive dd if=...
Turn off throttling temporarily
There are a bunch of sysctls available to tune the behavior of the I/O throttling system, including one to shut it off entirely:
# sysctl debug | fgrep lowpri_throttle
debug.lowpri_throttle_max_iosize: 131072
debug.lowpri_throttle_tier1_window_msecs: 25
debug.lowpri_throttle_tier2_window_msecs: 100
debug.lowpri_throttle_tier3_window_msecs: 500
debug.lowpri_throttle_tier1_io_period_msecs: 40
debug.lowpri_throttle_tier2_io_period_msecs: 85
debug.lowpri_throttle_tier3_io_period_msecs: 200
debug.lowpri_throttle_tier1_io_period_ssd_msecs: 5
debug.lowpri_throttle_tier2_io_period_ssd_msecs: 15
debug.lowpri_throttle_tier3_io_period_ssd_msecs: 25
debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled: 1
# sysctl -w debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled=0
debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled: 1 -> 0
